# What is the latest and effective method to check internet connection in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability, internet-connection

I want to know which is the latest and effective method to check internet connection in iOS.Most of the answers in stackoverflow is outdated it seems.I went through [REACHABILITY class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).It is working fine.But I have a problem.

I have a wifi connection which ask for provider login at times.So the reachability class shows that wifi connection is available however internet is not usable.

so,when I call a url,the activityIndicator that I am using along with the url keeps on spinning and I am getting no callback about the error.Is there a fix?Thanks.

Also,can you explain what these exactly means?

```
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *hostReachability;
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *internetReachability;
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *wifiReachability;
```

like,What is wifiReachability?Is it connected to wifi?or internet is available through wifi?

**EDIT:**
This is what I am using now.Creating a class called connectivity

```
#import "Connectivity.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
@implementation Connectivity
+(BOOL)checkConnectivity
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return networkStatus != NotReachable;
}
@end
```

Is this enough to check internetconnection?

Comment: I'm not sure (hence the comment), but I would *assume* `hostReachability` is whether or not the website can be reached, `internetRechability` is whether or not there is a internet connection (not necessarily a functional one), and `wifiReachability` is whether or not there is a connection to a wifi network (and not necessarily a working connection).

Comment: @Jojodmo - Your assumption is correct. Just to add, `internetReachability` checks for the default route on network, which is basically nothing but checking if internet can be connected without hitting a particular host. You should post it as answer.

Comment: I don't think you cannot check the `real internet connection` with `Reachability`. I would use a specific `REST API` and check the response is as expected.

Comment: That is a good trick! :)

Comment: Abhi refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk link

Answer (score 1):

Following is the another alternate very simple way to check internet connectivity:

```
NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/m"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
if (data)
    NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
else
    NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the internet");
```

Hope this will help.